# Find the output using typeof function

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, typeof

I am writing a code. And here I have a problem how can I fix that. I have an input line, it takes a string or a number. So I need to check what is the output and get the answer. I need to give a simple solution. So I can't use functions or something like that.

```
let input = prompt('Enter your text.');

if (typeof input === "string") {
    alert("You have string.");
} else if (typeof input === "number" && input > 30) {
    alert("number more than 30");
} else if (typeof input === "number" && input < 30) {
    alert("number less then 30");
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend storing `prompt` inside of the variable.

Comment: @Eloi Why not? The only alternative to `someVar = prompt(...)` is to call `prompt` multiple times, which is a completely different approach that OP hasn't indicated they want. OP wants *one* dialog, not multiple ones for each test.

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh my bad, I forgot that once input is executed the `prompt` disappears from the variable, TBH I have never use prompt in a real project :)

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` will **always** return a string.

If you want to check whether the string is composed purely of numerical values, you could use a regular expression:

```
if (/^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(input)) {
  // then it's purely numerical
  const num = Number(input.trim());
  // perform more operations on the number
} else {
  // it's not composed of only numerical characters
}
```

If you don't want to use a regex, you can use `Number` alone, but then you'll also include values like `Infinity` which might not be desirable, and since `Number('')` gives 0, you'll have to check for that separately:

```
const num = Number(input);
if (input.trim().length && !Number.isNaN(num)) {
  // then it's a number, use num
}
```

Another approach that I'd recommend is to [avoid `prompt` entirely](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj77rzfn4jwAhXaU80KHcjzAYIQFjABegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2577128%2Fwhy-javascript-dialogs-alert-prompt-confirm-are-not-widely-used-and-not-under&usg=AOvVaw23KIN4DKl_MyvkHdt4C10g). Consider using a proper modal instead, such as a form with an input box and a submit button.

In such a case, if you want to require a numeric input, just do:

```
<input type="number">
```

Comment: how can I do without regexp?

Comment: I suppose you can use `Number` alone instead, but I prefer the regular expression approach because its algorithm is more intuitive (to me)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago and this is what I did:

```js
function testNumber(test) {
  if (isNaN(test) === false) {
            console.log("this is a number");
            } else {
            console.log("this is not a number");
            }
}
testNumber(4); // number
testNumber("4") // number
testNumber("string") // not a number
```

You can replace "test" for a variable if you don't want to use a function

```
if (isNaN(myVar) === false) {}
```

And you may want to add more checks if you want to differentiate between 4 and "4"

Comment: This results in the empty string being detected as a number, which doesn't sound right.

Comment: You are right... I guess in my website this code was never executed if the string was empty... no I never realised. You could check if it is a String earlier with other `if``

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
let input = prompt('Enter your text.');
if(isNaN(Number(input))){alert("You have string.")};
if (Number(input) > 30) {
    alert("number more than 30");
} else if (Number(input) < 30) {
    alert("number less then 30");
}
```

So it can change all Stringed-numbers to numbers and check if they are number with the `isNaN` function